# I need help to get parameters from a route in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a parameter from a route to use for an API call. My code looks like this

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TaskViewComponent } from './pages/task-view/task-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: TaskViewComponent},
  {path: 'lists/:listId', component: TaskViewComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

task-view.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import List from 'src/app/models/list';
import Task from 'src/app/models/task';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss']
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {
lists: List[] = [];
tasks: Task[] = [];

constructor(
  private taskService: TaskService, 
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router 
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.taskService)
  this.taskService.getLists()
  .subscribe((lists: List[]) => this.lists = lists);

  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  const listId = params['listId'];

  if (!listId) return;
  this.taskService.getTasks(listId).subscribe((tasks: Task[])=> this.tasks = tasks)
})
}
}
```

list.ts

```
export default class List {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
}
```

task.ts

```
export default class Task {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    _listId: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

I want to get listId from the lists I get from the backend and use the listId to make another api call to the back end to get a list of tasks that I nan also display on the same template beside the list title. But the code is not working. When I log listId to the console, it is undefined.

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `listId` won't change, then you can use snapshot of params. So, you don't need to subscribe to params observable in this case.

```
ngOnInit() {
     const listId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listId');
     this.taskService
       .getLists()
       .subscribe((lists: any[]) => (this.lists = lists));

    this.taskService
        .getTasks(listId)
        .subscribe((tasks: any[]) => (this.tasks = tasks));
  }
```

But, in case if you expect the user to navigate from one list to other directly, then you can listen to change happening to params `listId`. You can do something like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.taskService
      .getLists()
      .subscribe((lists: List[]) => (this.lists = lists));
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
          const listId = params.get("listId");
          return this.taskService.getTasks(listId);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((tasks: List[]) => (this.tasks = tasks));
  }
```

Comment: @Binah kindly confirm if this answer worked for you or not.